# Changing class on object with jQuery does not allow me an onClick event of new class

Tags: php, jquery

I am allowing users to upvote an item.  When they click the up arrow, I have jQuery change the class of the arrow so that it turns green.  Now, if the user clicks that same arrow again, I want to create an event to change that arrow back to its original class, so they are undoing their vote (like stackoverflow voting: click once to upvote, click again to undo). Anyway here is my code.

These are the arrow classes in php generated on page load.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id = "' . $row['item_id'] . 'up"

        '; if ($row['upVote'] > 0) { echo '
            class = "used_upArrow"
           ';} else {echo '
               class = "new_upArrow"
               ';} echo '
                rowid="' . $row['item_id'] . '">
     </a>
```

Here is my jQuery changing the class on an upvote (among other things).  This all works perfectly.

```
//upArrow
 $('.new_upArrow').click(function(){
   var row = $(this).attr('rowid');
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "upVote.php?id="+row,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        $('.'+row).html(parseInt($('.'+row).html()) + 1);
        document.getElementById(row+'up').className = "used_upArrow";
        },
    error: function(result){
        alert('Voting error, please try again.');
        }
     });
});
```

Here is where the undoing should occur. So, `new_upArrow` should now be `used_upArrow`, and **this** script should fire on click.

```
 $('.used_upArrow').click(function(){
   var row = $(this).attr('rowid');
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "downVote.php?id="+row,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $('.'+row).html(parseInt($('.'+row).html()) - 1);
        document.getElementById(row+'up').className = "new_upArrow";
        },
    error: function(result){
        alert('Voting error, please try again.');
        }
    });
});
```

Checking firebug, the class is in fact changing **FROM** `new_upArrow` **TO** `used_upArrow`, but it continues to **UPVOTE** when clicked as if the class has no changed. Any ideas what is going on? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery live event binding](http://api.jquery.com/live/), eg

```
$('.new_upArrow').live('click', function(){
```

and

```
$('.used_upArrow').live('click', function(){
```

The reason your event binding isn't working is because the normal bind, eg `element.click()` is processed only once at the time of execution.

The live binder uses event delegation which will attach the handler to matching elements now and in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your problem is that the event handlers aren't getting installed for the .used_upArrow class when your code thinks it is.  When you change the className to "used_upArrow" here:

```
$('.new_upArrow').click(function(){
...
    success: function() {
        $('.'+row).html(parseInt($('.'+row).html()) + 1);
        document.getElementById(row+'up').className = "used_upArrow";
    },
}
```

The event handler for the other class will not be bound to the other .used_upArrow class. So, the same event handler will get called when you click the element, instead of switching event handlers. That is, calling `$('.used_upArrow').click(function() { })` will only bind that event handler for any elements that currrently have that class assigned to them at the time the event is bound, and not any elements that may acquire that class in the future through the triggering of other events.  Since the element doesn't get the `.used_upArrow` class until the `.new_upArrow` class is called, that event handler is probably never called.

You could rebind the event handler in the first event handler, but it's probably a lot simpler to add another class to both the `.used_upArrow` and .`new_upArrow` and then change behavior/state based on whether the element has one or the other classes, something like this:

```
<div class="upArrow <?php echo $row['upVote'] > 0 ? 'used' : 'new'; ?>" 
     id="<?php echo $row['item_id'] . 'up'; ?>"
     data-rowid="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
</div>

$('.upArrow').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).attr('data-rowid');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var list = [{
           incr: 1,
           url: 'upVote.php',
           thisClass: 'new',
           otherClass: 'used'
       },{
           incr: -1,
           url: 'downVote.php',
           thisClass: 'used',
           otherClass: 'new'
    }];
    var params = list[$(this).hasClass('new') ? 0 : 1];
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: params.url + "?id=" + row,
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      success: function() {
        $('.'+row).html(parseInt($('.'+row).html()) + params.incr);
        $(id).removeClass(params.thisClass).addClass(params.otherClass);
      },
      error: function(result){
        alert('Voting error, please try again.');
      }
    });
});
```

(This would also need you to change any CSS classes from `.upArrow_used` and .`upArrow_new` to `.upArrow.new` and `.upArrow.used`)

This way you don't have to change the event handler when the element changes state.

Comment: Fantastic reply, thank you! Phil suggested I use the .live attribute, which did work with what I was trying to acheive, however I think I would be able to take this a step further with your method.  Thank you very much for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you first bound the click events to used .new_upArrow, those events are registered to those who have the .new_upArrow class. That being said, when you changed the class to .used_upArrow, the event bindings did not change. Thus, you'll need to rebind the click event to the updated class.

Hope it helped. Cheers!